# the body is not stretched to the edge

Tags: css

so I'm creating a website and it's so important for me to finish it in time but I hit a problem that creates an annoying bug in android that that makes the body not stretch to the end of the page

here's how to remake this bug:

1. run the code that I will put below
2. go to Devtools
3. turn on mobile mode

heres the code :

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("buy-id").addEventListener("click", function() {
  localStorage.clear()
  localStorage.setItem("buy-item", "id");
  window.location.href = window.location.href + "/buy-gem-list";
});

document.getElementById("buy-details").addEventListener("click", function() {
  localStorage.clear()
  localStorage.setItem("buy-item", "details");
  window.location.href = window.location.href + "/buy-gem-list";
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: yekanbakh;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url(fonts/yekan-bakh-regular.ttf) format("truetype")
}

* {
  font-family: yekanbakh;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #e5e4f3;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: sticky;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(252, 244, 244);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}

.navbar>span {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 550;
}

.navbar>.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background: url("./images/logo.png");
  background-size: 56px;
  border-radius: 500%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #161616;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #020202;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.buy {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.buy>span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.buy>.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buy>.items>.item {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  background-color: rgb(204, 102, 102);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("images/gem.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 75px;
}

.buy>.items>.item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(223, 68, 68);
}

.social {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.social>span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.social>.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.social>.items>.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0 7px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.social>.items>.item>a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.social>.items>.item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(126, 107, 107);
}

.whatsapp-link {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.whatsapp-link>span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.whatsapp-link>.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.whatsapp-link>.items>.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0 7px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.whatsapp-link>.items>.item>a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.whatsapp-link>.items>.item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(126, 107, 107);
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 3em;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 55px;
}

.footer>.about {
  padding: 15px;
}

.footer>.about>span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.footer>.about>p {
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.footer>.copyright {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(225, 10, 10);
}

.itemss {
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 15px;
  direction: rtl;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.itemss>.item {
  margin: 1.25em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 3px solid #bbb;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.itemss>.item>.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.itemss>.item>.price {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: darkgreen;
}

.itemss>.item>.btn-buy {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(243, 54, 54);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.itemss>.item>.btn-buy>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.itemss>.item>.btn-buy:hover {
  background-color: rgb(197, 59, 59);
}

.itemss>.item>.gem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("../images/gem.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
}

.instagram {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-image: url("./images/instagram.png")
}

.telegram {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url("./images/telegram.jpg")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Viva Shop - فروش جم فیری فایر بسیار ارزان</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js" defer></script>
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#5f72da">
  <meta name="description" content="شرکت اینترنتی ویوا شاپ جزو بزرگترین فروشگاه های فروش جم بازی کامپیوتری فیری فایر است که کلی محصول با قیمت ارزان دارند">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <span>ویوا شاپ</span>
  </div>

  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="images/notAvalibale.png" height="250" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">عکس دریافت نشد</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="images/notAvalibale.png" height="250" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">عکس دریافت نشد</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="images/notAvalibale.png" height="250" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">عکس دریافت نشد</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>

  <!--     <center><img src="images/bannner.png"></center> -->

  <div class="buy">
    <span>خرید جم</span>
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item" id="buy-details">
        با اطلاعات
      </div>

      <div class="item" id="buy-id">
        با آیدی
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="social">
    <span>لینک فضای مجازی</span>
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="telegram"></div>
        <a href="https://t.me/vivashopgemhosein">تلگرام</a>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="instagram"></div>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/freefire_viva/">اینستاگرام</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="whatsapp-link">
    <span>لینک چنل های واتساپ</span>
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/LE3SQTYfj74LhqTRsZH7Yk">شعبه  1  واتساپ</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/GgwzSsveC1HFQO20bS5Aee">شعبه 2 واتساپ</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/F7VElY8b2bg2qzouUuCUW6">شعبه 3 واتساپ</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/JaP3U8vBRfVK7Hxt86kr6C">شعبه 4 واتساپ</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/Lwy7ufrRKIv4w2S53r9ral">شعبه 5 واتساپ</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <!-- <div class="support">
            <p>برای تماس با شرکت ویوا شاپ متن پیغامتان را وارد کنید</p>
            <div class="inputbox">
                <input type="text" name="text-msg" id="support-msg-text">
                <div class="submit" id="support-btn-submit">ثبت</div>
            </div>
        </div> -->

    <div class="about">
      <span>
                درباره ویوا شاپ
            </span>

      <p>
        ویوا شاپ یکی از بزرگ ترین فروشگاه های آیتم های قابل خرید بازی کامپیوتری فیری فایر است که تا کنون بیش از 100 مشتری داشته است و 6 شعبه در واتساپ دارد
      </p>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="copyright">
      © تمام حقوق این وبسایت متعلق به ویوا شاپ است و هرگونه کپی برداری پیگرد قانونی دارد
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

*you will get a headache looking at the code*

please help me i want to fix it fast

Comment: So does it happen only on Android? Coz I am unable to repro it on Android Chrome. BTW, nice use of words! 

Comment: yup, it only happens on android